# Remove elements with dot in their path doesnt work

Tags: php, arrays

I need to remove all elements that contains dot in array that i receive fron ftp_nlist(), this is how i do that:

```
$connection = ftp_connect($host);
if(!$connection){
    echo "Can't connect to $host ($login:$password)\n";
    #print_r(error_get_last());

    ftp_close($connection);
    exit();
}
ftp_login($connection, $login, $password);
ftp_pasv($connection, TRUE); 
$files_list = ftp_nlist($connection, $path);
print_r($files_list);
for($i = 0; $i< count($files_list); $i++){
    if( strstr($files_list[$i], '.') ){
        unset($files_list[$i]);

    }
}
print_r($files_list);
echo 'Ok';
```

However it works strange

```
Array
(
    [0] => /httpdocs/favicon.ico
    [1] => /httpdocs/mobile.html
    [2] => /httpdocs/g
    [3] => /httpdocs/index.html
    [4] => /httpdocs/.
    [5] => /httpdocs/member.html
    [6] => /httpdocs/sitemap.xml
    [7] => /httpdocs/animated_favicon1.gif
    [8] => /httpdocs/rakuten.html
    [9] => /httpdocs/y_key_8866d9fb86f18b30.html
    [10] => /httpdocs/robots.txt
    [11] => /httpdocs/..
    [12] => /httpdocs/bbs.html
    [13] => /httpdocs/version.php
    [14] => /httpdocs/css
    [15] => /httpdocs/nas
    [16] => /httpdocs/googlee7e5921970ceb672.html
    [17] => /httpdocs/about.html
    [18] => /httpdocs/images
)
Array
(
    [2] => /httpdocs/g
    [10] => /httpdocs/robots.txt
    [11] => /httpdocs/..
    [12] => /httpdocs/bbs.html
    [13] => /httpdocs/version.php
    [14] => /httpdocs/css
    [15] => /httpdocs/nas
    [16] => /httpdocs/googlee7e5921970ceb672.html
    [17] => /httpdocs/about.html
    [18] => /httpdocs/images
)
Ok
```

As you can see not all elements with dots was removed. I can't see clear reason why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you `unset()` an array element the `count()` in the condition is  decreased by 1.  So instead of using `count($files_list);` in the condition (this is evaluated each iteration), set it first so it doesn't change:

```
$count = count($files_list);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    if(strpos($files_list[$i], '.') !== false){
        unset($files_list[$i]);    
    }
}
```

I would prefer `foreach()`:

```
foreach($files_list as $key => $file){
    if(strpos($file, '.') !== false){
        unset($files_list[$key]);    
    }
}
```

Also notice that `strpos()` is better suited here.

Comment: Yeah, sure, I will take that into account.